# when I make pivot table it changes the order of rows

Tags: excel, vba

When I make a pivot table it changes the order of rows.

I have a big dataset. I have 35 industries and 41 countries so I have 35 x 41 = 1441 rows corresponding 16 energy carrier which are my columns. In each country, I have specific first 16 rows. It is very easy working with a pivot table however when I do pivot table it changes the order of rows of the original table. I have two screenshots the first one is the original table and when I make a pivot table it changes the order of the rows. I need the pivot table as the same order of the original table.
[image]

Trying to use excel pivot table.

No code

I want the same order of the original table in the pivot table. That would help a lot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

PivotCaches, the data storage for PivotTables, don't retain the order of data because generally it's meaningless and unless every category had every sub-category in the same order, it generally wouldn't be possible to determine an overall order anyway due to conflicts and gaps.

There are 3 possible methods to tell a PivotTable the order that you want and all of them start with a separate tab containing a unique list of all possible values in your desired order.

1. Insert a helper column in your data with the order number, `=MATCH(A2,*List*,0)-1`, then use that helper column as the first category for rows in your PivotTable and switch off subtotals
2. Insert a helper column that combines the order number with the industry names, `=TEXT(MATCH(A2,*List*,0)-1,"00") & A2, then use that as your only category for rows
3. Define a custom sort order list: Select your ordered list, then go to File > Options > Advanced > General > Edit Custom Lists..., then click Import, OK and OK again.

When you create a new PivotTable, Excel should automatically use the custom list as the sort order. If you need to apply the sort order to an existing PivotTable, just select any single industry row label then hit the Sort AZ button from the data tab.

(If it *still* doesn't recognize the list, then in your PivotTable, right click on industry field, click on Sort > More Sort Options..., select Ascending by industry field, then click More Options..., then untick AutoSort and select your custom list in the First Key Sort Order dropdown.

All of these options assume some proficiency in Excel. Let us know if you need more detail on your preferred option.